# Symmetric function $p_k({x_1},{x_2},...,{x_n})={x_1}^k+{x_2}^k+...+{x_n}^k$ on $GF(q)=\{0,a_1,a_2,...,a_{q-1}\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, symmetric-functions

This is the first time for me on symmetric functions. Let us consider the symmetric function $p_k({x_1},{x_2},...,{x_n})={x_1}^k+{x_2}^k+...+{x_n}^k$ on $GF(q)=\{0,a_1,a_2,...,a_{q-1}\}$.

I want to show that:

a) $p_{q-1}(a_1,...,a_{q-1})=-1$

b) $p_{k}(a_1,...,a_{q-1})= 0$ for all $0 < k \leq q-2$.

Some hints or procedure? $GF(q)$ is cyclic so for the first point there is some recursivity, but how can I handle this problem?

Comment: Don't forget that the nonzero elements of $GF(q)$ form a cyclic group.

Comment: This has been done on the site already. Did you search?

Comment: I seem to have answered it myself [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/707203/11619) as well as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1268426/11619). Not voting to close as a dupe though. No reason to think that would have been the first occurrence. Also, it is surely bad form to use my dupehammer to direct attention to my own answer.

Comment: Hmm. I may be feeding the search engine with wrong buzzwords...

Comment: [Matt Samuel came up with the same solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1399662/11619) proving that there is nothing original with mine.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen a little comment, thanks to you and to stack, in  march I passed my Algebra exams. Thank you so much (ps you can delete this comment after read for cleanup)